# Is this defined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void Print(const char* s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

std::string GetString() {
    std::string ret;
    ret = "Is this defined behavior?";
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    Print(GetString().c_str());
}
```

This code seems to work reliably on the big 3 compilers. I'm concerned that it might not actually be defined behavior, is it possible the string could be destroyed leaving the c_str() returned pointer dangling before the Print function is called?

https://godbolt.org/z/cKddvd1aP

Comment: The temporary returned by `GetString` will be alive long enough for `Print` to finish with the pointer to the temporary's data. Looks good to me.

Comment: Handy compiler option: `-fsanitize=address,undefined` Turns on a bunch of extra runtime checks. Doesn't get everything, but it gets a lot of cases where the scope ended too soon.

Comment: Reliable documentation on the lifetime guarantees: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime

Comment: And the relevant standard sections: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary and https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5

Comment: A noob mistake `return ret.c_str();` would be UB. This isn't.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly well-defined behavior.  `GetString()` returns a temporary `std::string`, which will be destroyed at the end of the *full expression* in which it was created.  That means it is destroyed on the `;` after `Print()` exits, thus the `c_str()` pointer will not be dangling inside of `Print()`.